# Convolutional neural network architecture calculation question

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I'm attempting to understand the neural network architecture used in this paper: [Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901.pdf).
Here's an image of the network achitecture from the paper that is bothering me:
[image: Architecture]

So in the first layer, a (224 x 224 x 3) image is convolved by 96 (7 x 7) kernels with a stride of 2. There is no mention of padding in the architecture description. Plugging these parameter values in the algorithm for the spatial size of the output volume from [the Wikipedia article on CONVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#Convolutional_layer), I have:

- W = 224
- K = 7
- P = 0
- S = 2
  This gives (W - K + 2P) / S + 1 = 109.5 
   According to commenters from a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580088/calculate-the-output-size-in-convolution-layer), we simply round down to 109 when the output of the formula is not an integer. I tested this out in Tensorflow and confirmed this. However, in this paper, the output size is not 109, but 110. So I guess they rounded up, but I don't understand why. This method of rounding up repeats itself throughout the network architecture.  
  Am I incorrectly applying this formula, were things done differently back in 2014 when the paper came out? Can anybody explain why they round up as opposed to down, and perhaps how I can do the same in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correctly applying the formula (with a typo in +1 in your post), and it's typically rounded down in many libraries. Some lower level libraries provide an option to round down or up, but I didn't see this in tensorflow or pytorch.

The paper is from 2014, where there was no tensorflow nor pytorch publicly available. So, everything was a bit less *standard* (not saying they're right now, but comparatively).

For this reason, I believe the paper used their own implementation according to their understanding and assumptions. The formula given does not hold for subsequent layers as well, where 13 x 13 matrices are turned into 13 x 13 matrices with 3 x 3 conv. operations.

It's hard to understand what exactly they did, but except the pooling from 55 to 26, every dimension seems to hold with padding = 1. The rounding up trick does not work for 13x13 kernels.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I assume they completely changed the process for the 13 x 13 matrices, since the stride has changed from 2 to 1 and they seem to use what tensorflow calls "same" padding. All in all, I'm disappointed in the clarity of the paper, but glad I got an explanation about the formula. (I'll fix the typo)